# Efficiently storing large numbers as powers of 2 for paths problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, shortest-path, kruskals-algorithm

I am trying to solve a modification of  the following problem: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135915/sum-of-all-paths-between-all-pairs-of-nodes-in-a-tree

**Description of the problem**: Find the sum of all shortest paths between all pairs of nodes in a tree. In the first line of input we get two numbers N and M which are the number of nodes and edges respectively. In the M lines after that we get input (a,b,c) where a and b are the nodes and c is the weight of the edge between them. However the actual weight is 2^(c). The output must print the binary representation of the sum of all shortest paths.

**My Solution**: I got one of the codes provided from the question linked and I performed kruskal's algorithm to get the all shortest paths.

**My problem**: I can't find a way to store the 2^(c) weights because c at most 2*10^(5) - 1.

My code so far:

```
﻿#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace std;
#define mp make_pair
#include <math.h>       /* pow */
typedef long long ll;
#define MOD 1300031
vector<vector<pair<ll, ll>>> g;
vector<ll> sum1, sum2, cnt;
vector<int> visited;
ll n;
#define edge pair<int,int>

void convertToBinary(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n / 2 != 0) {
        convertToBinary(n / 2);
    }
    printf_s("%d", n % 2);
}

class Graph {
private:
    vector<pair<int, edge>> G; // graph
    vector<pair<int, edge>> T; // mst
    int* parent;
    int V; // number of vertices/nodes in graph
public:
    Graph(int V);
    void AddWeightedEdge(int u, int v, int w);
    int find_set(int i);
    void union_set(int u, int v);
    void kruskal();
    vector<vector<pair<ll, ll>>> print(vector<vector<pair<ll, ll>>> g);
};
Graph::Graph(int V) {
    parent = new int[V];

    //i 0 1 2 3 4 5
    //parent[i] 0 1 2 3 4 5
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        parent[i] = i;

    G.clear();
    T.clear();
}
void Graph::AddWeightedEdge(int u, int v, int w) {
    G.push_back(make_pair(w, edge(u, v)));
}
int Graph::find_set(int i) {
    // If i is the parent of itself
    if (i == parent[i])
        return i;
    else
        // Else if i is not the parent of itself
        // Then i is not the representative of his set,
        // so we recursively call Find on its parent
        return find_set(parent[i]);
}

void Graph::union_set(int u, int v) {
    parent[u] = parent[v];
}
void Graph::kruskal() {
    int i, uRep, vRep;
    sort(G.begin(), G.end()); // increasing weight
    for (i = 0; i < G.size(); i++) {
        uRep = find_set(G[i].second.first);
        vRep = find_set(G[i].second.second);
        if (uRep != vRep) {
            T.push_back(G[i]); // add to tree
            union_set(uRep, vRep);
        }
    }
}
vector<vector<pair<ll, ll>>> Graph::print(vector<vector<pair<ll, ll>>> g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < T.size(); i++) {
        g[T[i].second.first].push_back(mp(T[i].second.second, T[i].first));
        g[T[i].second.second].push_back(mp(T[i].second.first, T[i].first));
    }
    return g;
}


void dfs1(ll node)
{
    visited[node] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < g[node].size(); i++)
    {
        ll x = g[node][i].first, w = g[node][i].second;
        if (visited[x]) continue;
        dfs1(x);
        sum1[node] += sum1[x] + cnt[x] * w;
        cnt[node] += cnt[x];
    }
    cnt[node]++;
}
void dfs2(ll node)
{
    if (node == 1)
    {
        sum2[node] = sum1[node];
    }
    visited[node] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < g[node].size(); i++)
    {
        ll x = g[node][i].first, w = g[node][i].second;
        if (visited[x]) continue;
        sum2[x] = sum1[x] + sum2[node] - sum1[x] - cnt[x] * w + w * (n - cnt[x]);
        dfs2(x);
    }
}

int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    long long int N, M;
    cin >> N >> M;
    Graph gr(N+1);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        int u, v, c;
        cin >> u >> v >> c;
        gr.AddWeightedEdge(u, v, pow(2,c));
    }
    gr.kruskal();

    int t, x, y, w;

    n = N;

        g.resize(n + 1); sum1.resize(n + 1); sum2.resize(n + 1);
        visited.resize(n + 1); cnt.resize(n + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            g=gr.print(g);
        }
        dfs1(1);
        visited.clear();
        visited.resize(n + 1);
        dfs2(1);
        double ans = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            ans += (double)sum2[i] / 2;
        }
        ll fans = (ll)ans;
        cout << fans;
        sum1.clear(); sum2.clear(); visited.clear(); cnt.clear(); g.clear();



}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, please consider using another naming style. Calling global variables the same single letter as a member variable but with different case (`g` and `G`), typedef-ing `long long` to `ll` and calling functions `dfs1` is not readable to anyone but yourself.

Now to your actual question: If c < 2 * 10^5, then log2(c) < 18. So c can be stored in any integer with more than 18 bits. For example a 32 bit int.

If you actually want to know how to print 2^c for c < 2 * 10^5, then I would do the following:

When the weight is always 2^c, its binary representation is always a `1` followed by c zeros (in case of negative c, you would get fractions instead of integers). So 2^1 in binary is `10`, 2^5 is `100000`, etc.

Knowing that, you can print 2^c this way:

```
void print_power_of_two(int c)
{
    std::puts("1");

    for(int i = c; i > 0; --i)
        std::puts("0");
}
```

Comment: But how would I store them and calculate the total sum

Comment: @thriteenchess As described in the answer, c can be stored in a regular 32bit integer. You cannot store the sums, because the sum of arbitrary powers of two can be any integer number, so you would need an integer with 2*10^5 bits. Theoretically, it would be possible to store a list of all c's you want to add up and you can compare the lists directly instead of the sums.